# display my pages html

Tags: customization

I am new to wordpress I have a big problem, I created a plugin that contain "pages" folder that contains all my html pages I want to display in my website but I do not know how to do what I found out how create a page of the additive, but displayed in the administration menu. I searched for tutorials but I have not found Please help!

Comment: Welcome at WPSE! So you created a plugin with html pages in it which you want to display on your site? Doesn't this contradict the whole idea of using a CMS like WordPress? But maybe I just don't understand your question. Please add some more info about what you have, what you want and what you already tried, including code. Also have a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My question is to display my custom pages in the frontend of the website

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for 'HTML pages' you might be interested on `page templates` or custom `themes` so I would like you to read a bit more about the Wordpress documentation called [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/). You can find information about how to create templates and themes.

Some of this links should help you:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

If you're already using either a templates or a theme and you want to display your pages on the public side have a look on this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Hope this help. Keep yourself updating, reading and looking on google, it helps a lot and will save you time.